# How to create image queue effect using CSS3, jQuery, and HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

How to create this effect using CSS, jQuery, and HTML?

[image]

Comment: `CSS filter` will help you - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: btw what did you try so far? do you have somethign to work on?

Comment: no.. i don't have working experience in css filters. :(

Comment: i added an answer, hope it helps you 

Comment: haii Thank you for your help. this is what i really want. Thank you once again. (y) :) .   I Have a doubt  is it increase the page loading time ???

Comment: no, it won't increase it, because you only make call 1 time for each image, the rest is css. take care with the `-webkit` prefix used in filters (you have to add the rest of prefixed for cross-browsing)

Comment: sure, thank you once again  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some free time at job, so here's an example of what you are looking for ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dwzhcwL/)):

[-] **html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://pipsum.com/200x150.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/150">
    </div>
</div>
```

[-] **js**

```
$('img', '.container').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.clone().addClass('top').insertBefore($this);
    $this.clone().addClass('mid').insertBefore($this);
    $this.addClass('bot');
});
```

[-] **css**

```
body { background: black; padding: 20px; }
.container { position: relative; display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px; width: 200px; }
.container img { display: block; border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; }

.container img.top,
.container img.mid,
.container img.bot { position: absolute; margin: auto; left: 0; right: 0; }

.container img.top,
.container img.mid { -webkit-filter: blur(.2px); }

.container img.top { opacity: .8; width: 80%; z-index: 0; -webkit-filter: brightness(80%); }
.container img.mid { top: 10px; opacity: .5; width: 90%; z-index: 1; }
.container img.bot { top: 20px; z-index: 2; }
```

And remember: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter